# ¿Como convertir un entero a un formato de pesos dominicanos en PHP?

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando un sistema de préstamos, para un cliente de republica dominicana, y necesito desarrollar un formato de moneda, que sea igual al de allá, estoy utilizando la función.

```
<?php 
 number_format($number, 2);
?>
```

Pero el cliente me dice que no es correcta las cifras que arroja esta función, y me gustaría hacerle el convertidor en su moneda.

Agradecería su ayuda amigos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Pero $number está directamente en pesos dominicanos o en otra moneda?
Si el número que tienes está en euros por ejemplo podrías convertirlo y mostrarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$numero = 5;
$diferencia = 0.0173022259;
$total = number_format($numero / $diferencia, 2);
echo $total + "pesos dominicanos";
```

El resultado de este ejemplo sería: 288.98 pesos dominicnos

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que lo mas sencillo és que calcules tu la cantidad de dinero pongamos:

```
$euro_dolar = 1.36;//Relacion 1€ 1.36$
```

Entonces el valor númerico a mostrar és:

```
 number_format($number*$euro_dolar, 2);
```

De esta forma multiplicas el valor  `$numero` en € para obtener el valor en $ y mostrarlo con el formato 2 de `number_format`